# Sql Server Query Divide by zero error encountered

Tags: sql-server-2008

I ma getting error in my query. how i can resolve it. i have tried null if but it is  not working.

Divide by zero error encountered

```
SELECT ( 100 - ( ( sum(t1.cAmount) - ( SUM(t1.cAmount) * t2.rAdvancedAmotizationPercent / 100 ) ) * 100 ) / t3.rAmount ) AS restofTotalMoblization,
       ( ( sum(t1.cAmount) - ( SUM(t1.cAmount) * t2.rAdvancedAmotizationPercent / 100 ) ) * 100 ) / t3.rAmount           AS totalMoblization
FROM   tblPkgAdvances t1
       INNER JOIN tblFianacialInvoice t2
         ON t1.vsSysPackageId = 'GWSSP/WS/03'
       INNER JOIN tblPkgContractAwardDetails t3
         ON t2.iPackageId = t3.iPackageId
WHERE  t1.vsSysPackageId = 'GWSSP/WS/03'
GROUP  BY t1.cAmount,
          t2.rAdvancedAmotizationPercent,
          t3.rAmount
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
(100 - ((sum(t1.cAmount) - (SUM(t1.cAmount) * t2.rAdvancedAmotizationPercent / 100)) * 100) / t3.rAmount)
```

you can do

```
case when t3.rAmount = 0 
then 0 
else (100 - ((sum(t1.cAmount) - (SUM(t1.cAmount) * t2.rAdvancedAmotizationPercent / 100)) * 100) / t3.rAmount) end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
SELECT ( 100 - ( ( sum(t1.cAmount) - ( SUM(t1.cAmount) * t2.rAdvancedAmotizationPercent / 100 ) ) * 100 ) / t3.rAmount ) AS restofTotalMoblization,
       ( ( sum(t1.cAmount) - ( SUM(t1.cAmount) * t2.rAdvancedAmotizationPercent / 100 ) ) * 100 ) / t3.rAmount           AS totalMoblization
FROM   tblPkgAdvances t1
       INNER JOIN tblFianacialInvoice t2
         ON t1.vsSysPackageId = 'GWSSP/WS/03'
       INNER JOIN tblPkgContractAwardDetails t3
         ON t2.iPackageId = t3.iPackageId
WHERE  t1.vsSysPackageId = 'GWSSP/WS/03' and t3.rAmount>0
GROUP  BY t1.cAmount,
          t2.rAdvancedAmotizationPercent,
          t3.rAmount
```

I have just filtered out records which are greater than 0